# Why can't i remove the 'All HD' menu item after jailbreaking my 1st Gen Apple TV?

Tags: jailbreak, appletv

I used ATV USB Creator to jailbreak my 1st gen ATV. I was able to remove all menus that I wanted by deleting the entries from the info.plist files. All, that is, except the 'All HD' item under TV shows. Why can't I delete it? It did not have an entry in the plist like all the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'All HD' menu (along with many others) apparently is loaded dynamically over the internet (presumably via a connection to the itunes store). If your Apple Tv is not connected to the internet this menu (along with others) will not show up.